# Trouble with roaming profiles and temporary profiles

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-profile, roaming-profile

So, here is the deal:

- rds sessions hosts (2k8r2) in a farm
- roaming profiles on a dfs share

A domain user (with a roaming profile setting) logs on a rds session host and this happens:

> Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a
>   temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when
>   you log off.

The thing is, the user doesn't have a local profile on the server and doesn't have a roaming profile saved on the dfs yet.

How do i "bypass" the temporary profile if neither profiles exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is, the user doesn't have a local profile on the server and doesn't have a roaming profile saved on the dfs yet.
>
> How do i "bypass" the temporary profile if neither profiles exist?

You don't.  A temporary profile is what Windows fails back to if it can't find or create a valid profile the user has permissions to.  If you want to Windows to stop failing back to a temporary profile, fix the problem with the user's roaming profile.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that i managed to mess up the NTFS permissions. I put the sec group on the share and somehow forgot to add the rest of the users/groups in that group. Well, a stupid mistake that can happen to anybody i guess :).

Ty